# Create a new policy in computer management Win 10 pro

Tags: administrator, windows-10-pro

I would like to create a new policy that should make users be able to install programs on the computer even a local user

Comment: [This seems awfully familar](https://serverfault.com/questions/1059006/automatically-add-certain-ad-users-to-local-admintrator#).  Are you just asking the same question as a new user?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that to some extent with Power Broker for Windows.

https://www.beyondtrust.com/resources/whitepapers/powerbroker-windows-mac-supported-platforms

> BeyondTrust PowerBroker for Windows and PowerBroker for Mac are least
> privilege and application control solutions that eliminate excessive
> or administrator privileges, maintain application control, and log
> privileged activities on physical and virtual Microsoft Windows
> servers and desktops, and Mac desktops. PowerBroker for Windows and
> PowerBroker for Mac helpIT and security teams to close security gaps,
> improve operational efficiency, and achieve compliance objectives.

Otherwise the standard user will need access to Admin Credentials and/or the Registry to make approved changes.

So it is not very likely the idea you have will succeed.

Comment: The truth is that I wanna make just one user have the rights to install software and he shouldn't have all other administrator options. So maybe your answer might help

Comment: I do not think that is at all likely with a created Computer Policy. Power Broker is a significant addition to Group Policies.

Comment: Yes it is an expensive product. And it requires detailed knowledge of Group Policies to install.

Comment: So it's not for me. Thanks for trying to help me

Comment: Without it and as I answered, a simple policy will not succeed at installing most software.